# Problem with Beamer + LuaLaTeX + format files

Tags: beamer, luatex, format-files

While trying to compile a beamer format file, I came across the following error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Using the command `lualatex -ini -jobname="fmttest" "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx "fmttest.tex"`. This format compiles fine with a beamer class (or with an article class). However, trying to **use** the format for the file test.tex (`lualatex -fmt=fmttest.fmt test.tex`):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Hello world!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Lualatex throws this error, and produces no other useful information:

```
! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Removing the begin/end frame pair and setting the class of fmttest.tex to article, everything compiles as expected. The same cannot be said for beamer... Why is this / Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution?